# Ternary operator with loop structure in gnuplot

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot, ternary-operator

I'm trying the following in gnuplot:

```
y(i,x) = i*x
plot for [i=1:10:1] i==1 ? y(i,x) lc rgb "red" title "retas": y(i,x) lc rgb "red" notitle
```

but it gives the following error:

```
gnuplot> plot for [i=1:10:1] i==1 ? y(i,x) lc rgb "red" title 'retas' : y(i,x) lc rgb "red" notitle
                                           ^
         expecting ':'
```

And adding parenthesis doesn't help.

I know that I can reach the result using this:

```
plot for [i=1:10:1] i==1 ? 1/0 : y(i,x) lc rgb "red" notitle, y(1,x) lc rgb "red" title "retas"
```

but why doesn't the first command work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap in a ternary operator construct only some isolated parts of the plotting command:

```
y(i,x) = i*x
plot for [i=1:10:1] (i==1 ? y(i,x) : alt(i, x)) lc rgb "red" title (i == 1 ? "retas" : "")
```

Comment: Yeah, this works pretty well! And it can be better `plot for [i=1:10:1] y(i,x) lc rgb "red" title (i==1 ? "retas" : "")`. It had a misprint on the code that I corrected: there is no `alt(i,x)`...